# What is a GCC toolchain?

Tags: gcc, toolchain

In which ways it can be an example of C/assembly/object/executable compiler?

I would like more pieces of information than the few ones Wikipedia gives about it.
Also, if you can link some sources where I could find more about it, it would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toolchain), a toolchain is:

> A set of tools for software development, often used in sequence so that the output of one tool comprises the input of the next.

GCC is the GNU Compiler Collection; i.e. a set of compilers for different languages from GNU. From the [official webpage](https://gcc.gnu.org/):

> The GNU Compiler Collection includes front ends for C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Ada, and Go, as well as libraries for these languages (libstdc++,...).

Therefore, the GCC toolchain is a set of applications and libraries to compile programs written in several languages. For instance, for the C and C++ languages, that includes tools like:

- **`cpp`** Preprocessor
- **`gcc`** C compiler
- **`g++`** C++ compiler
- **`gcov`** Test coverage program

And accompanying libraries like:

- **`libbacktrace`** Symbolic backtraces producer
- **`libquadmath`** Quad-Precision Math Library
- **`libstdc++-v3`** C++ Standard Library

Now, when someone refers to the GCC toolchain, typically they are also implicitly referring to other utilities that might not come from GCC's project/repository but are usually required for development. For instance, tools like:

- **`ar`** Archive manipulation program
- **`as`** Assembler
- **`c++filt`** C++ demangler
- **`ld`** Linker
- **`nm`** Object file symbol listing
- **`objdump`** Object file information dumper

If you are using the implementation of these tools from GNU, then you are using the [GNU Binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) project:

> The GNU Binutils are a collection of binary tools.

Comment: It is right to add also a debugger to the toolchain? so in this case gdb after objdump

Comment: @Mondo-Cane In the extended definition (which in practice is used), sure! In fact, many compilers come with a debugger.