# RISC-V Toolchain with Vector support

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm, riscv, riscv32

I am looking for a C/C++ toolchain that supports the RISC-V vector extension v1.0 as defined per official [spec](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec).

[Spike](https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-isa-sim) appears to support vector rvv1.0, but I am having trouble finding a toolchain to use it with.

Neither [GCC](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain) (I only see a branch for rvv0.9) nor LLVM (I am using LLVM/clang 13.0.0, which only goes up to rvv0.10) appear to support the latest spec.

Can somebody point me to a working toolchain or do I just have to wait some more for the tools to catch up?

Comment: Hello friend, how about to look into sifive repo, as they said, they have 1.0 rvv from past year. https://github.com/sifive/freedom-tools/releases

Comment: Yes, you are right. They do have vector support in GCC up to RVV-1.0 draft. But apparently, there is no further RVV development on GCC happening. So this appears to be a dead end in the longrun?

Comment: Who knows? maybe you should ask Kito Cheng?

Answer (score 5):

GCC support RVV1.0 feature now. You can use this:https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain. checkout `riscv-gcc` to `riscv-gcc-rvv-next` and `riscv-binutils-gdb` to `riscv-binutils-2.38`. Then you can have latest RVV1.0 features in GNU toolchain

To support auto-vectorization: use `-mrvv` compile options.

Answer (score 3):

now, at 8 dec 2021 you can use llvm + clang 14.0.0 3eda87732fbac6f316e9e83984ef9a90f962c381 with enabled vector support rvv 0.1.

1. Compile RISCV GCC TOOLCHAIN
2. Compile LLVM + CLANG + LLD
3. Add GCC Toolchain to llvm install folder, here described how you can do it [Using Clang to compile for RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580399/using-clang-to-compile-for-risc-v/69924225#69924225)
4. And finally vectorize with next keys:

   `clang -O2 -c -march=rv64gv0p10 test.ll -o test1.o -menable-experimental-extensions -mllvm --riscv-v-vector-bits-min=256 -mno-relax`

Here is an output - objdump file:
[image]
Objdump won't recognize instructions but you can see it if you emit assembler code with `-S` key:
[image]

Comment: In case anyone gets a `error: invalid arch name 'rv64gv0p10', unsupported version number 0.10 for extension 'v'` error with the architecture string above, newer clang versions accept `-march=rv64gv`.